# lein appengine-prepare fails

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, compojure, appengine-magic

I'm trying get Clojure/Compojure/appengine-magic to work by following the example at https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic

But when I run `lein appengine-prepare` I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" C:\Users\henrik\IdeaProjects\simple-example\lib\dev not found. (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: C:\Users\henrik\IdeaProjects\simple-example\lib\dev not found.
```

Have I missed something?

`lein new simple-example`

edit project.clj:

```
(defproject simple-example "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"] [appengine-magic "0.4.1"]])
```

`lein deps`

`lein appengine-new`

edit core.clj:

```
(ns simple-example.core
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [appengine-magic.core :as ae]))

(defroutes simple-example-app-handler
  (GET "/" req
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body "Hello, world!"})
  (GET "/hello/:name" [name]
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body (format "Hello, %s!" name)})
  (ANY "*" _
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body "not found"}))

(ae/def-appengine-app simple-example-app #'simple-example-app-handler)
```

`lein appengine-prepare`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states that `appengine-magic` should be added to the `:dev-dependencies`. I was able to reproduce your problem by creating a project from scratch and trying to run `appengine-prepare` when `appengine-magic` was in `:dependencies`.

So instead of:

```
(defproject simple-example "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"] [appengine-magic "0.4.1"]])
```

You should have:

```
(defproject simple-example "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[appengine-magic "0.4.1"]])
```

This should hopefully fix your problem.